# Is there a multiple upload reference widget for dexterity (quickupload widget for dexterity content type)

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm working on a dexterity content type that should be able to support multiple upload of images. What I want is to be able to use something like one of the [`collective.plonefinder` referencewidgets](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.plonefinder/trunk/collective/plonefinder/widgets/referencewidget.py).

I've looked at the examples documented for `collective.plonefinder` but their widgets only seem to be archetypes compatible.

I also looked at `collective.quickupload` (which provides the upload ability to `collective.plonefinder`), while I can create a behaviour which marks a dexterity content type as `IQuickUploadCapable`, I can't add a quickupload widget to a dexterity content type.

Answer (score 0):

I came across https://github.com/plone/plone.formwidget.multifile this week, never used it, but I had to think of it when I read your question, maybe it is worth checking out...

Comment: Checking it out, good to see that a version is in pypi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.formwidget.multifile even though it is alpha

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that https://github.com/collective/collective.upload is targeting this use-case, although I am not 100% sure there's a well-documented example of how to use it as a widget. Héctor Velarde may have some answers here.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading, if collective.plonefinder switched out collective.upload instead of collective.quickupload, I might have just what I'm looking for.